# Unable to update the system on Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: apt

Showing message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not use 'sudo' before your command in the terminal. That is why it tries to imply that you are not root.Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you will be asked for the password. Type it and press enter. Your update will start. Also note that when you type the password the * or the dots that appear normally when you type the password wont appear. Just type it without errors and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a root in order to update your sources list.

To do that you can use a fantastic utility called sudo.

Easily run the update command using sudo before

```
sudo apt-get update
```

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or
>          another user, as specified by the security policy.  The real and
>          effective uid and gid are set to match those of the target user, as
>          specified in the password database, and the group vector is initialized
>          based on the group database (unless the -P option was specified).